# Installing Laravel Backpack "no install"

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to install Backpack for Laravel on Windows Server 2012 (which may be part of the problem, but I can't find any instructions specifically for Windows). I'm following the directions [here](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/install-on-laravel-55#section-2-install-backpackbase), and everything goes fine until I need to run "`php artisan backpack:base:install`" at which point I get this error:

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Backpack\Base\Backpack\Base\app\Console\Commands\Install does not exist
```

I assume it has something to do with the duplication of the "Backpack\Base" part, but explicitly giving it the path without the duplication or just saying install results in the same error. Likewise, same error with any other artisan commands later in the guide, such as `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\CRUD\CrudServiceProvider" --tag="public"`. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the 3.3.0 release, which has since been fixed. You must have tried to install it within the 1-hour timespan until we had time to properly test the release. A `composer update` should fix it for you. You'll then be able to run `php artisan backpack:base:install` without a glitch.

Cheers!